# json string not parsing

Tags: json, string, syntax-error

I have to create an abacus as a json string, like this:

```
var jString = "'rTable':[{'1M=':'70'},{'1mv=':'70'},{'1mx=':'140'},{'1mxv=':'140'},{'1mxx=':'230'},{'1mxxv=':'230'}},{'1m+1':'90'}]";


var rTable = JSON.parse(jString);
```

When I try to parse it I got an **unspecified** "syntax error" message.
Are special signs like =, + and - allowed?
Can someone tell me what is wrong with this json string?

Once created I intend to get the values like this:

```
var score = "1M=";
var v = rTable[score];
```

Am I right?

Comment: FYI: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

1. Valid JSON must begin with `{` or `[`. Enclose the whole thing in `{}`, or remove `'rTable':`.
2. You have an extra `}` here: `{'1mxxv=':'230'}}`
3. Use double quotes instead of single quotes.

If your language/framework is not being specific enough about syntax errors, I'd suggest running the string through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. +1 for jsonLint tip.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few errors.

1) JSON requires it's non-numerical keys/values to be double quoted, single quotes just won't do.

2) As another poster pointed out, JSON must start with a `{` or `[`

3) You've got an extra `}` at `{'1mxxv=':'230'}},`

Here's your valid JSON:

`{"rTable":[{"1M=":"70"},{"1mv=":"70"},{"1mx=":"140"},{"1mxv=":"140"},{"1mxx=":"230"},{"1mxxv=":"230"},{"1m+1":"90"}]}`